# I can't use sound through HDMI in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, audio, multiple-monitors, hdmi, speakers

I am trying to connect my computer to a monitor and speakers using a single HDMI cable. My computer recognizes HDMI because my screen connects. However even after multiple attempts I can not make the sound work. Ubuntu does not recognize an HDMI output although with aplay gives me three HDMI output.

```
╭─simon@simon-UX305UA ~  
╰─$  aplay -l output
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CX20751/2 Analog [CX20751/2 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I try to use them with speaker-test but no sound comes out.

```
╭─simon@simon-UX305UA ~  
╰─$ speaker-test --channels 2 --rate 48000 --device hw:0,3 

speaker-test 1.1.3

Playback device is hw:0,3
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 2 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
Rate set to 48000Hz (requested 48000Hz)
Buffer size range from 64 to 16384
Period size range from 32 to 8192
Using max buffer size 16384
Periods = 4
was set period_size = 4096
was set buffer_size = 16384
 0 - Unknown
 1 - Unknown
Time per period = 4.588343
```

I tried every HDMI output with speaker-test
Thanks for reading

Comment: Prepend your command with `LANG=C ` to have output back in English so that people will be able to better read it and help you.

Comment: Have you tried all listed devices?

Comment: Yes but no one work

Comment: *Ubuntu does not recognize an HDMI output* This begs for clarification. Why do you say "does not recognize" and yet you have the device listed? Doesn't it appear in sound settings where you're supposed to select the output device? Or it's there but doesn't work? For the moment ignore the "test speakers" (a bug in 18.04, apparently) and do a real world test like playing something.

Comment: My HDMI output work i can have my second screen but sound don't want to work. I can't find HDMI output in my ubuntu sound settings even if i play something i can't use hdmi sound

Answer (score 0):

I had the same or very similar problem: When plugging in my HDMI cable to my laptop running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, the screen mirrored to the second display (Sony TV), but the sound continued to play through my laptop instead of the TV. I found that I had to manually switch the Output device in Sound Settings to the HDMI port.

[image: Screenshot: Sound Settings]

However, **before unplugging the HDMI cable**, you must select your default audio device again manually, otherwise you will have no sound even if you reboot your computer. (This is a bug.)